# onListItemClick add/replace fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

In my android app i would like to add/replace a fragment that contains several controls. This fragment has to be displayed on the right side of the list view and will replaced when the user selects a different item in the listview. I am testing with the ModeControls but i am unable to display it, so i need your support on this

below is the code

My tabs

```
public class Tab_Modes extends ListFragment {
private ArrayList<NameImg> items = new ArrayList<NameImg>();
private int crtMode;
private String str;
public Tab_Modes() {
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    //  Activity mActivity = activity;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    crtMode = arguments.getInt("position");
    str  = arguments.getString("frag");
    items.clear();
    switch (crtMode) {
        case 0:
            items.add(new NameImg("Manual", "Simple camera Control", R.drawable.hand));
            items.add(new NameImg("Bulb", "Long Exposure", R.drawable.bulb));
            items.add(new NameImg("Time Lapse", "Frame by Frame Movie", R.drawable.timelapse));
            items.add(new NameImg("HDR", "High Dinamic Range", R.drawable.hdr));
            items.add(new NameImg("IR", "Infra RED Control", R.drawable.ir));
            break;
        case 1:
            items.add(new NameImg("Triggered", "Trigger camera ", R.drawable.triggrered));
            items.add(new NameImg("Dark Room", "Long Exposure", R.drawable.darkroom));
            items.add(new NameImg("Lightning", "Frame by Frame Movie", R.drawable.lightning));
            break;
        case 2:
            items.add(new NameImg("Bullet", "Simple camera Control", R.drawable.bullet));
            items.add(new NameImg("Water drops", "Long Exposure", R.drawable.waterdrops));
            break;
        case 3:
            items.add(new NameImg("Manual", "Simple camera Control", R.drawable.pan_manual));
            items.add(new NameImg("Programmed", "Long Exposure", R.drawable.pan_auto));
            items.add(new NameImg("Star Tracking", "Long Exposure", R.drawable.starstracker));
            break;
        case 4:
            items.add(new NameImg("1", "USB1", R.drawable.usb));
            items.add(new NameImg("2", "USB2", R.drawable.waterdrops));
            break;
    }
    setListAdapter(new ModesItemAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.my_list_item, items));
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    //ListView myLV = null;
    //myLV = (ListView) myLV.findViewById(R.id.ItemView);
    //myLV.setItemChecked(0, true);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}

public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "selected Frag :" + str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    ModeControls myControls;
    myControls = (ModeControls) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_manual);
    if (myControls == null || !myControls.isInLayout()) {//if the fragment dosen't exists we create it
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString("myTxt", "selected item :" + position + " ID :" + id);
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        myControls = new ModeControls();
        myControls.setArguments(arguments);
        ft.add(R.id.pager, myControls).commit();
    }
}
```

}

and the fragment that i want to add

```
package com.grozeaion.www.gvicameraremotecontrol;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ModeControls extends Fragment {
    TextView textDetail;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle arguments = getArguments();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_manual_mode, viewGroup, false);
        view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        textDetail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_detail);
        textDetail.setText(arguments.getString("myTxt"));
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ModeControls " + arguments.getString("myTxt"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ModeControls " + getResources().getConfiguration().orientation , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return view;
    }
}
```

main activity xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity"
    >
    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />
    <com.grozeaion.www.gvicameraremotecontrol.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"/>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

main fragment xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:weightSum="1">
</LinearLayout>
```

and the fragment that i want to add

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_manual"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/f1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="F1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/f2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/f1"
        android:text="F2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/s1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="S1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/s2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/s1"
        android:text="S2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_detail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/s2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:text="New Text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Goodness, that's a lot of code. Have a look at "[*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and edit your question - it's not easy to see what's wrong in a series of blocks of code. *Where* is the problem?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the post and kept only the things needed. Basically i don't know how to add/replace the fragment_manual to the user interface on the right side of the listview. All the examples are adding the fragment in to main activity, but in my case i suppose thet the fragment has to be added in to the ViewPager.